# Dispatch undefined after binding to class in redux

Tags: javascript, scope, redux, undefined

Issue with a pattern i'm trying to use with redux.

I have a a mapDispatchToProps as below,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        presenter: new Presenter(dispatch),
    };
};
```

and my presenter constructor looks as below:

```
   constructor(dispatch) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatch;
   }
```

If I check the value of it in the constructor and after it's set, all is well.  However later when a method tries to use it, the value of dispatch is `undefined`.

If i save it to a var outside the class, i.e.

```
let dispatch;
class Presenter {
    constructor(dispatcher) {
        dispatch = dispatcher.bind(this)
    }
}
```

I've tried using `.bind()` within the first constructor also but it keeps becoming undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Class methods were of the form:

```
someMethod() {
    //do stuff
}
```

which means they have their own `this` scope bound... I'd have to bind the individual methods in the constructor, such as:

```
constructor(dispatch) {
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
    this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this);
}
```

Or turn them into => functions so they take their context from the surrounding class, i.e.

```
someMethod = () => dispatch(/* an action */);
```